# How do I fit a function to data that is monotonic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, data-analysis

I have a list of numbers that always increase. I would like to fit a function (any function, not necessarily a polynomial). I do have a condition to this function though which is as follows-

Let us say the data I have has 'n' values. I need the expression of the function to require at most 'n' constants to define it and for x ranging from 1 to n, it must produce the values of my original data exactly. This is already possible in polynomial fits. However, this function should also have the additional property that on substituting the value (n+1) to x, the result must always be greater than the value that results in the substitution of (n) to x. Basically, on extending the function to higher input values, the result must also increase.

I was wondering if I could use a series of exponentials as a function to form the required curve, but not being very familiar to hardcore math, I am not sure if or how to do it yet. If you think it is possible, I will surely look into figuring out an algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand. You say your series of numbers is increasing. Hence any function that is a good fit to that series should automatically be increasing. So I don't understand why you need your "additional property".

Comment: That is not true. As an example, the "y" values of a parabola first increases and then decreases, thereby not being a good fit. On extrapolating the function to values of x higher than the number of values considered, I need the function to still obey the property I seek

Comment: Exponentials $b^x$ with different bases are linearly independent, thus, by solving a system of linear equations you can find an exact fit for your data using sums of exponentials.

Comment: @Somos, could you provide an example or a link to one?

Comment: Something such as Mathematica code `f[n_] := c1*1^n + c2*2^n + c4*4^n + c8*8^n; Solve[
 f[1] == 22 && f[2] == 108 && f[3] == 664 && f[4] == 4656, {c1, c2, 
  c4, c8}]`? You have to choose the different bases ahead of time.

Comment: One last question - Can I prove that the function I get is monotonic? If I get one of the coefficients as negative, it is possible that the function isn't monotonic.